# Selenium findElements() returning size 0 when setting Chrome browser version above 115

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

I am running into an issue with the element size after upgrading to any browser version above V115.

**Code executed below when using chrome above V115**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBrowserVersion("121");
WebElement driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  
List<WebElement> c = driver.findElements(By.xpath("some_locator"));
System.out.println(c); // Prints 0
```

When I revert to V115, it prints the expected element count of 2.

I expected the correct element size.

These are the logs printed

chrome version 121. You can see that the array has no object in it.

```
<message>Executed: findElements (Response: SessionID: d0da1003d2cb1cc36e2e722a0a51b972, State: success, Value: [])</message>
```

chrome v115

```
<message>Executed: findElements (Response: SessionID: 5f98fa59345e281f1abe9a44d184fb2d, State: success, Value: [{element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=8695DA73894498B32E7C95AAD2D0F998_element_537}, {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=8695DA73894498B32E7C95AAD2D0F998_element_695}, {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=8695DA73894498B32E7C95AAD2D0F998_element_696}])</message>
```

- Selenium 4.18.1
- Chrome version 121
- Windows 10
- Java 8
- browser driver 121.0.6167.184

Any insight on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue.
Fixed by switching out of an iframe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).